# Error while installing hashicorp/aw: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aw

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

> terraform provider file for aws

provider.tf:

```
 provider "aws" {
  region = var.AWS_REGION
```

> terraform version file

```
version.tf:

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can i have solution please , trying for last couple of days , but still issue is not getting fixed

Answer (score 1):

Your error mentions "hashicorp/aw" twice, which is not "hashicorp/aws", is your provider.tf file saved with aws and not aw?

This is all you need in there, which mostly matches what you already have:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}
```